# htdocs path in linux

Tags: php, html, lighttpd

I am working on linux server through ssh and want to know where to put html and php files (the htdocs folder) but its seems to me the servers is running lighttpd

My directory structure looks something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That totally depends on your server configuration so your only reliable source of information should be lighttpd's configuration file which (if installed globally) should normally be within the /etc folder (e.g. /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf).

Popular locations for the htdocs folder are /var/www or somewhere within /srv.

Answer (score 5):

when xampp is installed -  /opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 4):

I would say it kind of depends on the configuration of your server.

Still, maybe something like `/var/www` would do, if it exists : this is the default, with many Linux distributions, for the HTTP root folder.

If it's not there, you should try to find the configuration file for Lighttpd (something like `lighttpd.conf`, probably somewhere under `/etc`) ; in that file, there should be the path for the `server.document-root`.

For more informations : [Lighttpd - TutorialConfiguration](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/TutorialConfiguration)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe that Arch Linux uses /srv/http as default in the apache-config (not sure about lighttpd though). However, it's easy to change.

Other than that, just look in the lighttpd-configuration file and you'll find your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

'`/var/www`' is where you should look. Most distros (actually, I don't know any that is not) put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked it up. Arch Linux sets the documentroot to /src/http for both apache and lighttpd fyi.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in Linux user: `opt/lampp/htdocs`.