# How to display PHP file on Apache?

Tags: php, apache

**NOTE:** *I'm using apache2 on Linux with PHP 5*

Suppose I had this simple hello_world.php file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World </p>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and I wanted to display it on my **apache2** server. How do I do this, and where do I move the source code? Thank you in advance

Comment: Move the file to /var/www, make sure www-data owns it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htdocs path in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582851/htdocs-path-in-linux)

Comment: The answer depends on where your Apache DocumentRoot resides. If you don;t know what that is, ask your web hosting provider.

Comment: In addition to what has already been suggested: Fix the missing `; ?>` and `'`'s around `<p>Hello World</p>`, and ensure that Apache is loading PHP, then you will probably be fine. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your files in /var/www and make sure Apache is launched.

Run the following command in a terminal :
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache start

After launch your browser (ex: Chrome) and type "localhost/hello_world.php" in your url adress bar.